# Sending POST request using Spring framework

Tags: mysql, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a MySql records table with a column called ConsignmentCode. I want to send an HTTP request to search the table by ConsignmentCode.

When I use Postman to do a POST request to http://localhost:8081/records/consignmentCode with `{consignmentCode: "123456789"}` in the body, I get a 404 Not Found error. Does anyone know why?

Controller class:

```
  /**
     * POST request to search by ConsignmentCode
     *
     * /records/consignmentCode
     *
     * Input ex: {consignmentCode: "123456789"}
     * @param params
     * @return
     */

    @CrossOrigin
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/consignmentCode",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public java.lang.String SearchRecordsByConsignmentCode(@RequestBody String params) {
        System.out.print("this SearchRecordsByConsignmentCode respond happened");
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(params);
        String likeConsignment= jsonObj.getString("consignmentCode");

        List<record> results=RecordDao.SearchRecordsByConsignmentCode(likeConsignment);
        obj.put("results", results);
        return obj.toString();
    }
```

Dao class:

```
 /**
     * Search by ConsignmentCode.
     *
     * @param consignmentCode
     * @return
     */

    public List<record> SearchRecordsByConsignmentCode(String consignmentCode) {
        final String sql = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE ConsignmentCode = ?";
        List<record> Record = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<record>() {
            public record mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int Id) throws SQLException {
                record records = new record();
                records.setId(resultSet.getInt("Id"));
                records.setNumber(resultSet.getString("Number"));
                records.setTitle(resultSet.getString("Title"));
                records.setScheduleId(resultSet.getInt("ScheduleId"));
                records.setTypeId(resultSet.getInt("TypeId"));
                records.setConsignmentCode(resultSet.getString("ConsignmentCode"));
                records.setStateId(resultSet.getInt("StateId"));
                records.setContainerId(resultSet.getInt("ContainerId"));
                records.setLocationId(resultSet.getInt("LocationId"));
                records.setCreatedAt(resultSet.getDate("CreatedAt"));
                records.setUpdatedAt(resultSet.getDate("UpdatedAt"));
                records.setClosedAt(resultSet.getDate("ClosedAt"));
                System.out.print(records);
                return records;
            }
        }, consignmentCode);
        return Record;
    }
```

Comment: Well, your DAO class has probably nothing to do with the error. You should put a breakpoint inSpring's  DispatcherServlet and see where the error is debugging the doService method.

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
@RequestBody String consignmentCode
```

instead of:

```
@RequestBody String params
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to expect to receive a String and then parse as JSon. It is a built in behaviour in Spring MVC.

Just import jackson-dependencies. In case you use Maven, add in your pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Then change your controller this way:

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/consignmentCode",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Record> SearchRecordsByConsignmentCode(@RequestBody ConsignmentCode code) {
        System.out.print("this SearchRecordsByConsignmentCode respond happened");

        List<Record> results=RecordDao.SearchRecordsByConsignmentCode(code.getConsignmentCode());
        return results;
    }
```

You will need to create this class which encapsulates the message body:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ConsignmentCode implements Serializable {

    private String consignmentCode;

    public String getConsignmentCode() {
        return consignmentCode;
    }

    public void setConsignmentCode(String consignmentCode) {
        this.consignmentCode = consignmentCode;
    }   


}
```

And then, start it and try posting to your controllers url this message (remember to set Accept/Content-Type headers to `application/json`). The property name must go between semicolons too, just this way:

```
{"consignmentCode":"123456789"}
```

And you will get the correct result in json format